# possible to use jQuery to select an element before another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible using jQuery to select a `<tr>` (which I have no class target to) right before another `<tr>` which I can target with a class '`active`'.

The list can be displayed in a random order, below is an example, so I can't use `nth` to target where it falls here, it needs to be based on the superseding `<tr class='active'>`

For example

```
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr> // this is the one I want to be able to select.
<tr class='active'></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you done some research? jQuery .prev().

Comment: I have and only came across `.before()` did not find prev, I take a look thanks

Comment: there is a page on jQuery that list every DOM traversal methods. For futur reference, check it out! http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$('.active').prev()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to select previous sibling

```
$('.active').prev('tr')
```

> **Description:** Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.